# New Jupyter Notebook instance always opens even with nbopen

Tags: jupyter-notebook, desktop-application, raspberry-pi-os

I have Jupyter Notebook (6.4.12) installed via pip on Rapberry Pi OS (Raspbian bullseye (11), 5.15.56). I can double-click on `.ipynb` files, and they start a new Notebook instance as expected.

I installed the nbopen (0.6) package via pip *after installing Notebook and restarting* and ran `python3 -m nbopen.install_xdg`, expecting that double-clicking a file will now open it in an existing Notebook instance where possible.

However, the old behavior has continued. No error messages are produced, and changing `nbopen.desktop` at `~/.local/share/applications/` to use `nbopen %f` or `python3 -m nbopen %f` have changed nothing.

Using `nbopen <file>` in terminal works as I would expect it to.

Why has this not worked, and what can I do to fix this to the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises from Jupyter Notebook's `jupyter-notebook.desktop` registering Notebook as the primary way to open `.ipynb` files. If you restart, it will remain cached as the primary way, even if you remove the appropriate line from the `.desktop` file.

Since both call themselves "Jupyter Notebook" when opening files, and `nbopen` effectively fails to Notebook's default behavior, it *may* be clearest to just remove Jupyter as a way to open `.ipynb` files:

In `~/.local/share/applications/jupyter-notebook.desktop` remove the line `MimeType=application/x-ipynb+json;` or comment it out with `#`.

In `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`, change the line`application/x-ipynb+json=jupyter-notebook.desktop;nbopen.desktop;` to `application/x-ipynb+json=nbopen.desktop;`

If you do not wish to remove Jupyter Notebook as a way to open`.ipynb` files, you can skip removing the line in `jupyter-notebook.desktop` and instead reorder the two entires in `mimeinfo.cache`.